# Simple Issue With cURL

Tags: php

i am in the closing stages of an sms application that will send different sms messages to different phone numbers. I will be using an sms gateway and my research led me to use cURL to implement the smpp api of the company that has the gateway. I was doing a test run of cURL on my localhost to see if all went smoothly before i implemented on the application(i wanted it to insert values into a table), but it was not working. So i need help on where i am doing something wrong.Here is my code. Thanks.

```
include 'sms_connect.php';
$sql="select name from sms";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $name=$row['name'];
   $url = "http://localhost/sms/index.php?name=".$name;
   // create a new cURL resource
   $ch = curl_init();

   // set URL and other appropriate options
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

   // grab URL and pass it to the browser 
   curl_exec($ch); 
}
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Define not working. Any error messages? Anything in the logs? Anything at all?

Comment: Do you have the cURL module loaded in php.ini? (uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`). Try `$output = curl_exec($ch); var_dump($output);`

Comment: I mean it is not inserting the data into the database on my localhost

Comment: Then we need to see the code for where you're inserting into the database once you've confirmed the other posters questions.

Comment: Ok..guys...i have uncommented curl in php.ini and turned on error reporting. This is the error i got: Notice: Use of undefined constant link - assumed 'link' in /srv/www/htdocs/sms/sms_connect.php on line 6 Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /srv/www/htdocs/sms/load.php on line 9 Notice: Undefined variable: ch in /srv/www/htdocs/sms/load.php on line 32 Warning: curl_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /srv/www/htdocs/sms/load.php on line 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
 $results = $curl_exec($ch);
 echo $results;
```

Look at the output. If you get the output you expect, the problem is when you insert the data in the database, if not - you have a problem with your cURL, and post the error message here.